# What's included in a Verilog always @* sensitivity list?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, digital-logic

I'm a bit confused about what is considered an input when you use the wildcard `@*` in an `always` block sensitivity list.  For instance, in the following example, which signals are interpreted as inputs that cause the `always` block to be reevaluated?

From what I understand, **clk** and **reset** aren't included because they don't appear on the right hand side of any procedural statement in the `always` block.  **a** and **b** are included because they both appear on the right hand side of procedural statements in the `always` block.

But, where I'm really confused about is **en** and **mux**.  Because they are used as test conditions in the *if* and *case* statements, are they considered inputs?  Is the `always` block reevaluated each time **en** and **mux** change value?

```
module example
( 
    input wire clk, reset, en, a, b,
    input wire [1:0] mux,
    output reg x,y, z
);

always @*    
begin  
 x = a & b;    
  if (en)
    y= a | b;
  case(mux)
    2'b00: z = 0;
    2'b01: z = 1;
    2'b10: z = 1;
    2'b11: z = 0;
  endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any signal that is read inside a block, and so may cause the result of a block to change if it's value changes, will be included by `@*`. Any change on a read signal used *must* cause the block to be re-evaluated, as it could cause the outputs of the block to change. As I'm sure you know, if you hadn't used `@*` you'd be listing those signals out by hand.

In the case of the code you've provided it's any signal that is:

- Evaluated on the right hand side of an assignment (`a` and `b`)
- Evaluated as part of a conditional (`en` and `mux`)

...but it's any signal that would be evaluated for any reason. (I can't think of any other reasons right now, but maybe someone else can)

`clk` and `reset` aren't on the sensitivity list because they aren't used. Simple as that. There's nothing special about them; they're signals like any other.

Comment: Identifiers in nested event expressions are not added.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the following signals are included in the implicit sensitivity list:

```
a
b
en
mux
```

`clk` and `reset` are not part of the sensitivity list.

This is described completely in the IEEE Std for Verilog (1800-2009, for example).  The IEEE spec is the best source of detailed information on Verilog.  The documentation for your simulator may also describe how `@*` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
always@*   // same as always@(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
begin
  result = a && b;
  if (c==d)  flag = e;
  $display("%0d",f);
  case (g)
    h : value = i;
  endcase
  arr[j] = k;
end
```

Here we can see that implicit sensitivity list automatically fetches those variables that are **being read** (like-: RHS and other arguments) by the always block.
In your case it would be : a, b, en, mux.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer depends on if you are writing RTL, or a testbench.  If you are writing RTL then you should try to forget about the concept of Sensitivity lists, as they don't really exist.  There is no logic that only updates when an item on the list is triggered.  All sensitivity lists can do in RTL is cause your simulation and actual circuit to differ, they don't do anything good.

So, always use "always @*" or better yet "always_comb" and forget about the concept of sensitivity lists.  If the item in the code is evaluated it will trigger the process.  Simple as that.  It an item is in an if/else, a case, assigned to a variable, or anything else, it will be "evaluated" and thus cause the process to be triggered.

But, just remember, in digital circuits, there is no sensitivity list.